# Way to include two fragment in one fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

Currently there are two fragment : one for the area for adding image view, text view. 
The other is a list fragment

I would like to include both in one fragment , that means the area fragment is at the top of the list fragment , however, they are two class so how to include them , or I need to re-arrange the code to one class?

Also, how do I change the list fragment to fragment ?(Since setadapter and onclick event are not available in fragment class).Thanks.

code example : the List fragment part

```
public class SlidingMenuListFragment extends ListFragment {
    protected List<SlidingMenuListItem> slidingMenuList;
    private SlidingMenuBuilderBase slidingMenuBuilderBase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // We set here a custom layout which uses holo light theme colors.
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list, null);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // We get a list from our specially created list data class.
            slidingMenuList = SlidingMenuList.getSlidingMenu(getActivity());
            if (slidingMenuList == null)
                    return;

            // We pass our taken list to the adapter.
            SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(
                            getActivity(), R.layout.sliding_menu_holo_light_list_row, slidingMenuList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // We could define item click actions here, but instead we want our builder
    // to be responsible for that.
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            l.setSelection(position);
            SlidingMenuListItem item = slidingMenuList.get(position);
            slidingMenuBuilderBase.onListItemClick(item);
    }

    // We can not provide a builder as an argument inside a fragment
    // constructor, so that is why we have separate method for that.
    public void setMenuBuilder(SlidingMenuBuilderBase slidingMenuBuilderBase) {
            this.slidingMenuBuilderBase = slidingMenuBuilderBase;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 4.2, you can use [Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). 
And to older versions, you should use the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)